# Getting and Setting value to Firebase Instance in Android Studio

Tags: android

I tried to set a value from MainActivity and get it to my FirebaseInstance class.

but I get this error,

```
Process: com.administrator.mosbeau, PID: 17713
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.administrator.mosbeau/com.example.administrator.mosbeau.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.administrator.mosbeau.FirebaseSetGet.setCountryid(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

here's what I did.

i created a **FirebaseSetGet** class

```
public class FirebaseSetGet extends Application {

    private String countryid;
    private String customerid;


    public String getCountryid() {

        return countryid;
    }

    public void setCountryid(String acountryid) {

        countryid = acountryid;

    }

    public String getCustomerid() {

        return customerid;
    }

    public void setCustomerid(String acustomerid) {

        customerid = acustomerid;
    }

}
```

then i tried to add this code in my MainActivity.

```
private void displayUserDetails() {
    User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();

    customersid = user.customers_id;
    countrycode = user.customers_countryid;
    stateid = user.customers_stateid;

    if (customersid == "") {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IndexActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        idsvar.setCountryid(countrycode);
        idsvar.setCustomerid(customersid);
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
    }

    if (productId != null){
        if (productFragment != null) {
            if (productFragment.equals("productItem")) {
                ProductFragment productfragment = ProductFragment.newInstance(productId, productName, countrycode, customersid, categoryName, stateid, categoryId);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, productfragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then get it to my FirebaseInstance

```
    public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    FirebaseSetGet idsvar = new FirebaseSetGet();

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        final String country_id  = idsvar.getCountryid();
        final String customer_id = idsvar.getCustomerid();

        registerToken(token,country_id,customer_id);
    }

    private void registerToken(String token, String country_id, String customer_id) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("Token",token)
                .add("Countryid",country_id)
                .add("Customerid",customer_id)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://shop.mosbeau.com.ph/FCM/register.php")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but it gives me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, passing values to `FirebaseInstanceIdService` would be a bad approach.

Why not play with `SharedPreferences`.

When token is refreshed, just save the token in preferences as below:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
       SharedPreferenceUtils.getInstance(this).setValue(getString(R.string.firebase_cloud_messaging_token), token);
    }
}
```

And after that I created a method in my BaseActivity to get that token from preferences as below:

```
public String getDeviceToken() {
    return SharedPreferenceUtils
            .getInstance(this)
            .getStringValue(getString(R.string.firebase_cloud_messaging_token), "").equals("")
            ? FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
            : SharedPreferenceUtils.getInstance(this).getStringValue(getString(R.string.firebase_cloud_messaging_token), "");
}
```

So, by doing this way, I am storing the newly generated token in preferences, and created a global point of accessing it for using it later.

You can go this way. Ask if you need more clearance on it..

**Edit:** Its a utility class that we have created to work easily with SharedPreferences.

You can get it from [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/chintansoni202/f1767fbe68f7f897cfb3096e8cd83480).

Comment: hi Chintan, thank you for your help.. sorry im new to android.. can you help mo to construct my code? i update my code.. thanks.. i tried your code but im getting error in SharedPreferenceUtils.

Comment: cannot resolve symbol firebase_cloud_messaging_token

Comment: @Joehamir If using Studio, then move your cursor to error portion just press alt + enter, it will show option with `create string value resource "firebase_cloud_messaging_token"`.. from there you can create resource.

Comment: Ok thanks, now how can i implement this code to insert my token, country_id and customer_id to my database? please check my code at the top. `FirebaseInstanceIDService ` thanks

Comment: @Joehamir I have two suggestions for you: Firstly, try to climb the stairs one by one. Secondly, try to cook, never ask for ready-to-eat.

Comment: it works now. thank you for your advice.. that suggestions answered my problem hahaha.. thank you.. :D

Answer (score 0):

The object of FirebaseSetGet class is not initialized first initialize it

```
FirebaseSetGet idsvar = new FirebaseSetGet();
```

now you can call method of FirebaseSetGet class.

Comment: not working.. is it possible to pass value from MainActivity to FirebaseInstanceIdService?

Comment: please see edit. i update my FirebaseInstanceIDService code.